# Use Like in a single SOQL query

Tags: soql, query, account, set

I have fixed set of Account Names stored in one custom object.

```
Set<String> NameSet = new Set<String>();
```

Custom object NameSet account Name values: **Intel, HP, Dell, IBM** etc

I have a query on Account object.  My Account Names are **Intel-Aus, HP, Dell-US, IBM etc**

```
List<Account> accList = [Select Name from Account where Name IN: NameSet]
```

The above accList only gives 2 records HP and IBM!

Intel and Dell do not come in the list because these account names have "hyphen" in it.

How do I write the query to get all the Account Names using %Like% in a single query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this way

Create set of string `%Name1%`, `%Name2%`etc

```
List<String> lstString = new List<String>{`%Name1%`, `%Name2%`, `%Name3%`};
List<Account> accList = [Select Name from Account where Name LIKE: lstString ];
```

### Updates

```
List<String> lstString = new List<String>{'%Intel%', '%HP%', '%Dell%' , '%IBM%'};

for(Account obj : [Select Name from Account where Name LIKE: lstString ]){
    system.debug(obj);
}
```

This will return all the Accounts with name **Intel-Aus, HP, Dell-US, IBM.**

[image]

Comment: but my problem is the other way.   Name1-123 LIKE %Name1%.   Will your query work for this too?

Comment: @sfdcFanBoy what do you want ?

Comment: I meant are these 2 same: (%Name1-123% LIKE Name1)  and (Name1-123 LIKE %Name1%) ?

Comment: Exactly.  So, if you see my Account Names are Name1-123, Name3-xyz (with hyphens) where as the Set contains just Name1, Name3.   So, will the LIKE get the results?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36400/discussion-between-ratan-and-sfdcfanboy).

Comment: Both return same! (%Name1-123% LIKE Name1) and (Name1-123 LIKE %Name1%)

Comment: @sfdcFanBoy you can add into query both `%Name1-123%` and `%Name1%` and check the result you will get to know the result..